# How to create a Follower following model in GraphQL?

Tags: data-structures, database-design, graphql, schema, aws-appsync

I saw many tutorials/article they have mentioned that following/followers field as an integer in user model in GraphQL schema. I know those are for demo purpose. But I don't know how to save the followers/following users with proper relational model and how unfollow works. I saw Twitter developer site [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/user) they mentioned their user model as follows:

```
{
    "id": 6253282,
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "screen_name": "TwitterAPI",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA",
    "profile_location": null,
    "followers_count": 6133636,
    "friends_count": 12,
    "listed_count": 12936,
    "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
    "favourites_count": 31,
}
```

I don't know whether this is their original code or prototype. But I'm confused how they are saving the follower userID.

**1.** How can we create proper follower/following model in graphQL?

**2.** Also how to create post likes/dislikes in GraphQL?